# C# HttpWebRequest appends some strange characters in header just before POST characters

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, fiddler, httpwebresponse

all

I am having some strange errors that I have never experienced before.

Usually I send GET and POST via C# HttpWebRequest.

The code is so simple as below.

```
HttpWebRequest _req             = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Url);
_req.Method                     = "POST";

var _keyValArray                = PostData
    .Select(s => s.Key
        + "="
        + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(s.Value, Encoding)
        )
    .ToArray();
var _keyValString               = string.Join("&", _keyValArray);
byte[] _postData                = Encoding.GetBytes(_keyValString);

this._SetHeader(ref _req, ref CookieContainer, ref Headers, Constant.ContentType.Application.WwwFormUrlEncoded, Referer, _postData.Length);

using (Stream _sw = _req.GetRequestStream())
{
    _sw.Write(_postData, 0, _postData.Length);
    _sw.Close();
}

using (var _res = (HttpWebResponse)_req.GetResponse())
{
    CookieCollection.Add(_res.Cookies);

    // Get html response
    using (var _sr = new StreamReader(_res.GetResponseStream(), Encoding))
    {
        _html       = _sr.ReadToEnd();
        _sr.Close();
    }
    _contentEncoding    = _res.ContentEncoding;
    _status             = _res.StatusCode;
    _responseUri        = _res.ResponseUri;
    _res.Close();
}
```

Then this code usually creates http post data as below.
[image]

Yes, it's fine. No problem at all.

But when I post again to the same url with different body, some strange characters are appended to the post packet as below.
[image]

This gives me 404 error

I think it is becuase the server cannot recognize the proper protocol method.

Has anyone seen some error like this?

Is this created by the server or my C# code?

Those characters are 9 length and it changes every time.

Comment: Is there **anything** that you are using between two requests?

Comment: @PeterCsala I don't quite understand your question. Between the first post and the second post, there is nothing.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I was typing too fast and missed the *re* prefix. So, is there anything which is reused during subsequent calls? Or do you create everything (every object) each and every time from scratch?

Comment: @PeterCsala Actually that code is in some class. So basically between first and second posts, HttpWebRequest and sub-objects are created from the scratch.

Comment: Funny thing is if I delay to send second post, it works fine. So, it seems like those 9 characters are created from the server.

Comment: You can try to set `keepAlive` to false to disable HTTP/TCP session reuse. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.keepalive?view=net-5.0#System_Net_HttpWebRequest_KeepAlive

Comment: @Robert It seems like working fine. I modified the first post packet's keepAlive to close, and it started to work now. Many thanks.

Comment: Very interesting. Assuming the HTTP implementation of Fiddler is correct this would effectively mean that the .Net Http client has bug that makes appear data of a request in a following request if the connection is reused.

Comment: @Robert I am still not sure if my client is making those 9 characters, or it is response from the server packet. Anyway, it used to work with other web sites even if I turn true to keepAlive.